# Failed to decode downloaded font in jsf

Tags: jsf, fonts, decode, facelets

For some reason my locally stored font is not being decoded correctly in my jsf application. I've tried everything, and at this point I'm at a loss.

This is the css reference (located in project/resources/text - same as font files)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'BunkenTechSansStd-Med';
  src: url("#{resource['text/30B733_0_0.eot']}");
  src: url("#{resource['text/30B733_0_0.woff2']}") format('woff2'),
       url("#{resource['text/30B733_0_0.woff']}") format('woff'),
       url("#{resource['text/30B733_0_0.ttf']}") format('truetype');
}
```

The sheet is referenced in the template as:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="text" name="MyFontsWebfontsKit.css"></h:outputStylesheet>
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css"></h:outputStylesheet>
```

The error I'm receiving in chrome is stated as follows (for all three files):

```
"failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:1717/javax.faces.resource/text/30B733_0_0.woff2.jsf"
```

Here's is the folder structure:

[image]

Furthermore the mapping is as follows:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>eot</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>otf</extension>
    <mime-type>font/opentype</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>svg</extension>
    <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>ttf</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-font-ttf</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>woff</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-font-woff</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>woff2</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-font-woff2</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

And lastly a pic of the error in dev tools:

[image]

Comment: Why is it trying to load `30B733_0_0.woff2.jsf` instead of `30B733_0_0.woff2`? Where is that secondary `.jsf` extension coming from?

Answer (score 0):

JSF apparently requires folder nav as ":" instead of backslashes.

```
@font-face {font-family: 'BunkenTechSansStd-Med'; src: url("#{resource['text:30B733_0_0.eot']}");
src: url("#{resource['text:30B733_0_0.woff2']}") format('woff2'),
url("#{resource['text:30B733_0_0.woff']}") format('woff'),
url("#{resource['text:30B733_0_0.ttf']}") format('truetype');}
```

Comment: Using `library="text"` and `library="css"` is in first place wrong. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/11988415